# How to get actual value for duplicate index MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, key, on-duplicate-key

I am interacting with MongoDB using C# driver. It threw duplicate key error like below for one index

the highlighted value **0x141214141a24** is not a actual value in the error message of location.path. how to get the actual value of it? (location.target is actual value I see)

Message : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: Database.Collection index: location.path_1_location.target_1 collation: { locale: "en_US", caseLevel: false, caseFirst: "off", strength: 1, numericOrdering: false, alternate: "non-ignorable", maxVariable: "punct", normalization: false, backwards: false, version: "57.1" } dup key: { location.path: "**0x141214141a24**", location.target: 457 }" } ].

Comment: I think that is the "actual" value that is being indexed as the index has a non-simple locale. So basically you need to convert the locale representation of the value into the human readable representation)

Comment: @user20042973 no. This is not the actual value. If I query in database location.path:"0x141214141a24" , no document returned

Comment: My be, actual value is ``336861732``?

Comment: @ValNik unfortunately no. I dont see any document with this id

Comment: What type is ``location.path``?

Comment: @ValNik location.path is string & location.target int

Comment: What type is location.path in MongoDb?

Answer (score 0):

> @user20042973 no. This is not the actual value. If I query in database location.path:"0x141214141a24" , no document returned

What I was attempting to say is that `0x141214141a24` is the *representation* in the the specified collation of the value that is being sent to the database. I think the value being submitted by the client in your case is `"101149"`:

```
> db.foo.insertOne({location:{path:'101149', target:457}})
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.foo index: location.path_1_location.target_1 collation: { locale: "en_US", caseLevel: false, caseFirst: "off", strength: 1, numericOrdering: false, alternate: "non-ignorable", maxVariable: "punct", normalization: false, backwards: false, version: "57.1" } dup key: { location.path: "0x141214141a24", location.target: 457 }
```

Comment: thank you so much. yes you are correct, 101149 is the actual value. Let me know how you extracted the value and 0x141214141a24 is in which format?